# Configuração de Headers da response

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, express.js, vue.js

Criei um servidor em Express e o meu cliente em Quasar/VueJS. Preciso mandar um PDF para o meu cliente, o PDF em questão já está criado no servidor, mas estou enfrentando problemas para mandar ele para o cliente. Estou usando o axios para fazer as requisições do lado do cliente. Segue código abaixo:

Cliente:

```
axios({
      url: '/server/gerarpdf',
      method: 'post',
      data: this.pessoas,
      type: 'application/json',
      responseType: 'application/pdf'})
    .then(function (response) {
      let file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
      let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
      window.open(fileURL)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
```

Servidor:

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Tabela.pdf');
    let filePath = "C:/Projetos/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf";
    let fileName = 'PDF.pdf'; //
    res.download(filePath, fileName, function (err, results) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else {
            console.log('Baixou!!')
        }
    });
```

Antes o PDF não abria, agora ele abre mas fica em branco, sendo que quando abro ele manualmente todo o conteúdo dele aparece normalmente.
A minha dúvida é: Quais os Headers que devo configurar tanto no servidor quanto no cliente?? E como faço para que quando ele abra não ficar com o endereço da Blob que estou usando, tipo isso: "bb560c1c-5d9e-429a-8330-80e2e55e0a42"??

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Qual é a versão do Express que estás a usar? Vendo na documentação não encontro nada a dizer que tens de settar os headers. O `.download` não faz isso já?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 4.15.0, e eu já tentei várias coisas e nada está funcionando, ao menos preciso configurar os Headers no lado do cliente, coisa que também não estou conseguindo fazer de forma que o download do PDF ocorra.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste https://stackoverflow.com/a/7288883/2993657. Acredito que poderá lhe ajudar.

Comment: Já consegui fazer com que o download ocorra agora há pouco, usando um outro código, agradeço a sua ajuda, porém, o PDF está vindo corrompido.